# Kill respawing server running on port 3000 created by `node . > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &`

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, background-process, aws-code-deploy

I'm using [AWS CodeDeploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html) in which server running on [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) dose not work due to explanation given [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-long-running-processes) in troubleShoot documentation.

I followed the documentation and in **AfterInstall script** used `node . > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &` to run the node server in the background.

I've tried following ways to kill the server

- `fuser -k 3000/tcp`
- `lsof -P | grep ':3000' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`
- `kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:3000)`

but each time a **new process respwans with a different PID**.

How can I kill this background process and add it to the **ApplicationStop script** for **CodeDeploy**?

Comment: You need to add an applicationstop hook with your killing srcript. It'll be called when stopping the CodeDeploy service. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923991/amazon-web-service-codedeploy-appspec-yml-problems

Comment: @xvan: I have added ApplicationStop script in which I was trying the above commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to kill using `pkill node` command.

Answer (score 3):

One of the problems with finding a pid with grep is that the grep pid will also show up as a result and can kill itself before the target, so try;

```
ps ax | grep node | grep -v grep
```

if it looks reasonable, review this;

```
ps ax | grep node | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'
```

then run the kill;

```
ps ax | grep node | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

`pkill` is a less flexible option (no regex filtering) but if you use that be sure to use the `-I` flag so you don't kill anything you did not intend to.