# Script does not exist at specified location

Tags: aws-code-deploy

"Script does not exist at specified location: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/76b33ccc-594b-4d58-a1b8-e40d054c64b7/d-AVYMCK28I/deployment-archive/scripts/Applicationstoptest.sh"

This is the error I am getting can any one please help me how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using relative paths in your appspec.yml.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I followed this process and it did helped me.

The `ApplicationStop` hook is being called from the previously installed deployment before trying to run the current deployment `appspec.yml` file.

In order to prevent this from happening you'll have to remove any previously installed deployment from the server.

- Stop the code deploy agent - `sudo service codedeploy-agent stop`
- clear all deployments under `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root`
- Restart the code deploy agent - `sudo service codedeploy-agent start`

[copied ans from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27925591/1056283) so don't have to open new link.
Thanks @paul

Answer (score 0):

The paths used in source in the AppSpec file are relative paths, starting from the root of your revision. Also please make sure the appspec.yml file and the other files in the application bundle are not wrapped inside another folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27925591/1056283

The application stop hook uses a previous deployment to look for the script to invoke, so if the structure of your deploy package changes, there may not be a script to call at the specified location yet. The deploy fails and the script never arrives at the new location. Look in the linked answer for the steps to resolve it.